# Rails custom submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to control the *submit_tag* in the form to invoke different action to the default 'update' action?

I tried to use the submit_tag below, but it still redirect me to 'update' action in people controller.

```
<%= submit_tag "Save", :controller => "people", :action => "set_password", :method => "put" %>
```

The reason why I'm doing this is that, 
I have two update forms for the Person class, one for updating the basic information, and one for updating the password. I would like to handle the form submit differently.
For 'updating password form', i have to something additional. 
* validate the additional user input (current password)
* direct to 'update password' form if there is an error

Am I doing the wrong thing? Or I should distinguish the cases inside the 'update' method?

Comment: This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878195/ruby-on-rails-i-have-two-forms-how-do-i-move-the-submit-tag-of-one-form-inside-a/6878470#6878470

Comment: thanks james, so is handle different form submit in the same 'update' method a good structure in ror?

Comment: It's your only option! You can not have a form inside a form and as @kain points out it's the form declaration that determines the path/route/controller action that will be called not the submit buttons

Answer (score 7):

You have to tell the form where to go, not on the `submit_tag`:

```
<%= form_tag @object, url, :method => 'PUT' %>
```

Comment: You can have multiple submit tags but they will go to the same controller. This question has been answered loads of times - See here for one example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878195/ruby-on-rails-i-have-two-forms-how-do-i-move-the-submit-tag-of-one-form-inside-a/6878470#6878470